# How can I get an entity from Wikipedia without using "=", while iterating through a list?

Tags: input-forms, free-form-input, wikipedia, webservices

I have a list of entities from Wikipedia. I'd like to get the "entity" e.g. when I do something like:

= Elon Musk

I get:

[image]

But now I want to iterate through a list of entities, e.g. {Elon Musk, Bill Gates, ...} and get their net worth like so:

[image]

But in order to do that I need the light orange 'entity' I think?

Because if you look at the input form, there seems to be some ID following the name:

[image]

Comment: `ReverseSortBy[{#, 
    DecimalForm[
     QuantityMagnitude[SemanticInterpretation[#]["NetWorth"]], 
     DigitBlock -> 3, 
     NumberSeparator -> "\[ThinSpace]"]} & /@ {"Elon Musk", 
   "Bill Gates", "Jeff Bezos"}, Last]`

Comment: Thank you so much Bob! Works beautifully